# Riak container does not start when its data volume is mounted

Tags: docker, riak, docker-container, docker-volume, riak-ts

The following command works perfectly and the riak service starts as expected:

> docker run --name=riak -d -p 8087:8087 -p 8098:8098 -v $(pwd)/schemas:/etc/riak/schema basho/riak-ts

The local `schemas` directory is mounted successfully and the `sql` file in it is read by riak. However if I try to mount the riak's `data` or `log` directories, the riak service does not start and timeouts after 15 seconds:

> docker run --name=riak -d -p 8087:8087 -p 8098:8098 -v $(pwd)/logs:/var/log/riak -v $(pwd)/schemas:/etc/riak/schema basho/riak-ts

Output of `docker logs riak`:

> + /usr/sbin/riak start
>   riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
>   see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
>   If you want to
>   wait longer, set the environment variable
>   WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the
>   number of seconds to wait.

Why does riak not start when it's logs or data directories are mounted to local directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is with the directory owner of mounted `log` folder. The folder `$GROUP` and `$USER` are expected to be `riak` as follow:

```
root@20e489124b9a:/var/log# ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 riak riak   4096 Jul 19 10:00 riak
```

but with volumes you are getting:

```
root@3546d261a465:/var/log# ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul 19 09:58 riak
```

One way to solve this is to have the directory ownership as `riak` user and group on host before starting the container. I looked the UID/GID (`/etc/passwd`) in docker image and they were:

```
riak:x:102:105:Riak user,,,:/var/lib/riak:/bin/bash
```

now change the ownership on host directories before starting the container as:

```
sudo chown 102:105 logs/
sudo chown 102:105 data/
```

This should solve it. At least for now. Details [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259).