# Bitbucket container fails

Tags: ubuntu, docker, permissions, bitbucket, digital-ocean

I'm trying to set up a container, using Docker and Bitbucket server version `4.2`.

I use the following commands to start the container and set up a volume (This is recommended by the Bitbucket website): https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/docker-atlassian-bitbucket-server

(I'm adding sudo to every command)

```
For Bitbucket 4.12+
In Bitbucket 4.12 and later versions, volume permission is managed by entry scripts. To get started you can use a data volume, or named volumes. In this example we'll use named volumes.
$> docker volume create --name bitbucketVolume
$> docker run -v bitbucketVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket --name="bitbucket" -d -p 7990:7990 -p 7999:7999 atlassian/bitbucket-server
```

I have done it on 2 different machines (cloud and my laptop) with `sudo` and I'm still getting the following errors:

> A fatal error has occurred
>
> The following problems occurred, which prevents Atlassian Bitbucket
>   from starting:
>
> Bitbucket Home [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket] exists but
>   is not readable by Bitbucket Unable to create and acquire exclusive
>   lock file '/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/.lock' for
>   Bitbucket home directory '/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket'.
>
> Please ensure that the user running Bitbucket has permission to write
>   to this directory.
>
> If this is already the case, please check the logs for more
>   information.

The container logs contain errors about permission denied. Why?

The following error occurs on Digital Ocean cloud.
(I'm getting the same errors while doing the same on my laptop (ubuntu))

```
    Using BITBUCKET_HOME:      /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:47.938 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:47.943 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.592 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlValidation' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.592 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlNamespaceAware' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.658 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent An older version 1.1.32 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of 1.1.33
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.658 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.32 using APR version 1.5.1.
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.659 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015)
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.810 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-7990"]
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.828 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 810 ms
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.865 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:48.865 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
    09-Dec-2017 10:03:56.790 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    10:03:56,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
    10:03:56,862 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
    10:03:56,862 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/opt/atlassian/bitbucket/atlassian-bitbucket/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
    10:03:57,035 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
    10:03:57,045 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - About to instantiate property definer of type [com.atlassian.stash.internal.logback.AccessLogFormatPropertyDefiner]
    10:03:57,047 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - Popping property definer for property named [accesslog.format] from the object stack
    10:03:57,061 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - About to instantiate property definer of type [com.atlassian.stash.internal.logback.HomeDirectoryPropertyDefiner]
    10:03:57,062 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - Popping property definer for property named [home.dir] from the object stack
    10:03:57,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - About to instantiate property definer of type [com.atlassian.stash.internal.logback.LogFormatPropertyDefiner]
    10:03:57,082 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - Popping property definer for property named [log.format] from the object stack
    10:03:57,082 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - About to instantiate property definer of type [com.atlassian.stash.internal.logback.ProfileLogFormatPropertyDefiner]
    10:03:57,083 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - Popping property definer for property named [profilelog.format] from the object stack
    10:03:57,268 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - About to instantiate property definer of type [com.atlassian.stash.internal.logback.LogDirectoryPropertyDefiner]
    10:03:57,269 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.DefinePropertyAction - Popping property definer for property named [log.dir] from the object stack
    10:03:57,269 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
    10:03:57,274 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [bitbucket.application]
    10:03:57,312 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    10:03:57,406 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
    10:03:57,409 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-%d.log for the active file
    10:03:57,416 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-%d.log'.
    10:03:57,416 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
    10:03:57,421 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Sat Dec 09 10:03:57 UTC 2017
    10:03:57,426 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.application] - Active log file name: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log
    10:03:57,426 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.application] - File property is set to [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log]
    10:03:57,428 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.application] - Failed to create parent directories for [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log]
    10:03:57,429 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.application] - openFile(/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log (Permission denied)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:149)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:86)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
        at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
        at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:141)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:120)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:331)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:283)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:304)
        at  at com.atlassian.stash.internal.lifecycle.DefaultStartupManager.<clinit>(DefaultStartupManager.java:18)
        at  at com.atlassian.stash.internal.spring.StashWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(StashWebApplicationInitializer.java:68)
        at  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    10:03:57,429 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
    10:03:57,429 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [bitbucket.profiler]
    10:03:57,430 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    10:03:57,461 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
    10:03:57,462 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler-%d.%i.log for the active file
    10:03:57,464 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@10ce6982 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler-%d.%i.log'.
    10:03:57,464 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@10ce6982 - Roll-over at midnight.
    10:03:57,465 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@10ce6982 - Setting initial period to Sat Dec 09 10:03:57 UTC 2017
    10:03:57,469 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.profiler] - Active log file name: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler.log
    10:03:57,469 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.profiler] - File property is set to [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler.log]
    10:03:57,470 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.profiler] - Failed to create parent directories for [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler.log]
    10:03:57,470 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.profiler] - openFile(/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-profiler.log (Permission denied)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:149)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:86)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
        at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
        at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:141)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:120)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:331)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:283)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:304)
        at  at com.atlassian.stash.internal.lifecycle.DefaultStartupManager.<clinit>(DefaultStartupManager.java:18)
        at  at com.atlassian.stash.internal.spring.StashWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(StashWebApplicationInitializer.java:68)
        at  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    10:03:57,470 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
    10:03:57,470 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [bitbucket.accesslog]
    10:03:57,471 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    10:03:57,479 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
    10:03:57,479 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access-%d.%i.log for the active file
    10:03:57,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@4db4ac39 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access-%d.%i.log'.
    10:03:57,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@4db4ac39 - Roll-over at midnight.
    10:03:57,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@4db4ac39 - Setting initial period to Sat Dec 09 10:03:57 UTC 2017
    10:03:57,483 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.accesslog] - Active log file name: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access.log
    10:03:57,483 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.accesslog] - File property is set to [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access.log]
    10:03:57,484 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.accesslog] - Failed to create parent directories for [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access.log]
    10:03:57,484 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.accesslog] - openFile(/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket-access.log (Permission denied)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:149)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:86)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
        at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
        at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
        at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:141)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:120)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:331)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:283)
        at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:304)
        at  at com.atlassian.stash.internal.lifecycle.DefaultStartupManager.<clinit>(DefaultStartupManager.java:18)
        at  at com.atlassian.stash.internal.spring.StashWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(StashWebApplicationInitializer.java:68)
        at  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    10:03:57,484 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
    10:03:57,485 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [bitbucket.auditlog]
    10:03:57,485 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    10:03:57,491 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use gz compression
    10:03:57,492 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/audit/atlassian-bitbucket-audit-%d.%i.log for the active file
    10:03:57,494 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@32934525 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/audit/atlassian-bitbucket-audit-%d.%i.log.gz'.
    10:03:57,494 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@32934525 - Roll-over at midnight.
    10:03:57,495 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@32934525 - Setting initial period to Sat Dec 09 10:03:57 UTC 2017
    10:03:57,496 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.auditlog] - Active log file name: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/audit/atlassian-bitbucket-audit.log
    10:03:57,496 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.auditlog] - File property is set to [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/audit/atlassian-bitbucket-audit.log]
    10:03:57,496 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.auditlog] - Failed to create parent directories for [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/audit/atlassian-bitbucket-audit.log]
    10:03:57,496 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[bitbucket.auditlog] - openFile(/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/audit/atlassian-bitbucket-audit.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/audit/atlassian-bitbucket-audit.log (Permission denied)


    ........................................................
    ........................................................
    ........ stackoverflow questions` length limit.........
    ........................................................
    ........................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with permission of `bitbucketVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket` you need to make sure `bitbucketVolume` has the right permissions.

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183678/riak-container-does-not-start-when-its-data-volume-is-mounted/45187491#45187491) should help you with the solution.